# How can I load / open / read a matlab file *.mat in java?

Tags: java, matlab, opencv, mat, mat-file

My code so far (based on [this entry](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDwQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9731967%2Freading-data-from-matlab-into-java&ei=3vs0VezkJoSesgGnp4CACg&usg=AFQjCNHMEOpP86Aj5IFWoCByALGS4L2kVQ&sig2=EYKfIiVN49fcoeuFHbwqTQ&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGg)) but it doesn't work:

```
MatFileReader matfilereader = new MatFileReader("C:\\data\\Freebase\\initEmbed.mat");
System.out.println(matfilereader.getData().get(0) + "name: "+matfilereader.getMLArray("words").getSize());
System.out.println("new "+matfilereader.getMLArray("words"));
MLArray words = matfilereader.getMLArray("words");
System.out.println(words.contentToString().substring(0, 100));
MLChar j = (MLChar) matfilereader.getMLArray("words");
```

My output:

```
[1x91898  cell array]name: 91898
new [1x91898  cell array]
words = 
    [1x9  char array]   [1x3  char array]   [1x1  char array]   [1x1  char array]   [1x2  char array]   

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jmatio.types.MLCell cannot be cast to com.jmatio.types.MLChar
    at NTN.Run_NTN.main(Run_NTN.java:91)
```

How to load the words of this matlab file into a java array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about matLab, but the exception seems pretty clear. You're casting an `MLCell` to a a `MLChar`. "`getMLArray`" must be returning an `MLCell`.  I would cast to an `MLCell` first

```
MLCell mlCell = (MLCell) matfilereader.getMLArray("words");
```

And then use whatever methods are available on that type to get the `MLChar`.